# Ionic 2 Storage for browser and mobile

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, local-storage, ionic2

Before RC0 Ionic 2 had the possibility to use local storage like this:

```
storage = new LocalStorage(SqlStorage, options);
```

I used this in my app and it worked in both, browser (*ionic serve*) and mobile (*build/run*).

Now there is a only ***LocalStorage*** or ***SecureStorage***, which apparently both do not work in browser (*serve*).

Is there any other possibility to use a storage/database system which works for both, **browser and mobile**?

I am glad about any help.

Comment: You can try to use SQLite plugin for mobile and falling back to WebSQL when on browser with an IF/ELSE statement @sonia

Comment: ionic run browser instead of ionic serve browser

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/

Answer (score 2):

Now (Ionic v2.0.1) you can use Storage like:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class MyApp {
  constructor(storage: Storage) {

     storage.ready().then(() => {

       // set a key/value
       storage.set('name', 'Max');

       // Or to get a key/value pair
       storage.get('age').then((val) => {
         console.log('Your age is', val);
       })
     });
  }
}
```

more datails on https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage